# Sequelize query Substructures

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have a problem when I want to query Substructures in Sequelize:

I have user class and an album class and the user can have many albums.

If I want to query whether a user has one album it works fine with:

`user.findAll({include: { model: album, where: { band: 'Metallica', title: 'Master of Puppets'} } })`

The problem arises as soon as I want to know whether a user has two or more specific albums. So what I need is like: "array of connected albums contains both, album A as well as album B."

I tried:

`user.findAll({include: { model: album, where: {[Op.and]: [{ band: 'Metallica', title: 'Master of Puppets'}, {band: 'Iron Maiden', title: 'Fear of the Dark' }] } } })`

But that seems to apply the "and" on the wrong level and turn it into: band ='Metallica' and band='Iron Maiden', which of course never returns anything. So I got kinda stuck figuring out how to apply the "and" on the correct level.

I also tried the "any" or "contains" operators since I'm querying a pg, but they only seem to work with plain arrays not arrays of objects.

`user.findAll({where: {album: {[Op.contains]: [{ band: 'Metallica', title: 'Master of Puppets'}, {band: 'Iron Maiden', title: 'Fear of the Dark' }] } } })`

always throws an error saying { band: 'Metallica', title: 'Master of Puppets'} is an invalid value. The same is true for "Op.any" and "Op.contained".

`user.findAll({where: {album: {[Op.and]: [{[Op.any]: { band: 'Metallica', title: 'Master of Puppets'}}, {[Op.any]:{band: 'Iron Maiden', title: 'Fear of the Dark' }}] } } })`

fails because "Op.any" can't take an Object as input either, saying { band: 'Metallica', title: 'Master of Puppets'} is an invalid value

Does anyone know a solution to that?

Answer (score 0):

try using [Op.or]
this should give you  band ='Metallica' or band='Iron Maiden'
so users having band metallica or band iron maiden will show up

Comment: I did, and the "Op.or" actually does work as expected. The problem is I only want those who have both and "Op.or" gives me all users who have one of them or both.

Comment: i did not understand what you mean by both or gives all user who have one of them or both

Comment: if you use Op.or will give you  (band='metallica' and title='master of puppets') OR (band='iron maiden' and title ='fear of the dark') this will give you records if the user has one or both of the conditions

Comment: Sorry if that was unclear. I want user who have album { band: 'Metallica', title: 'Master of Puppets'} AND album {band: 'Iron Maiden', title: 'Fear of the Dark' }. So what I am looking for is kind " array of albums contains both "

Comment: the query is inside include clause so it will search for both condtion true in album model. that is not correct the query should be outside of include clause

Comment: yes, the problem is, outside the include clause it doesn't know the keys "band" and "title", since those don't belong to user but to album

Comment: and if I do it like:
`user.findAll({include: {model: album}, where: {[Op.and]: [{ "album.band": 'Metallica', "album.title": 'Master of Puppets'}, { "album.band": 'Iron Maiden', "album.title": 'Fear of the Dark' }]}})`
it doesn't know about user.album.title because probably "include" is executed after "where"

Comment: could you post the user and album model how you have defined them?

Comment: `sequelize.define('album', {
    AlbumID: {
      type: DataTypes.BIGINT,
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true
    },
    UserID: {
      type: DataTypes.BIGINT,
      allowNull: false
    },
    title: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(255),
      allowNull: true
    },
    band: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(255),
      allowNull: true
    }})`

Comment: `sequelize.define('user', {     UserID: {       type: DataTypes.BIGINT,       allowNull: false,       primaryKey: true     },     name: {       type: DataTypes.STRING(255),       allowNull: false     },     email: {       type: DataTypes.STRING(255),       allowNull: false     }})`

Comment: `user.hasMany(album, { foreignKey: "UserID" })`

Comment: do it the other way around use the service of album to do so like album.findAll(attribute: ['UserId'],
where: {[Op.and]: [{ "band": 'Metallica', "title": 'Master of Puppets'}, { "band": 'Iron Maiden', "title": 'Fear of the Dark' })

Comment: I tried it and unfortunetly it doesn't work. I don't think I can query album for two completly different instances.